# Calculate probability of word occurence

Tags: python, beginner, hash-map

I am pretty new in Python and I am not sure if I did everything right in my program. May someone to check it, please. Thank you!

1. First of all, I have a text file, for example, `abc.txt`.
2. I have to create a dictionary and for this, I have to split the
   sentences into a list of words and convert each word to lowercase.
3. Then I have to assign a counter to each word in my dictionary and
   increment it every time when I meet this word in sentence one more
   time.
4. Finally, I have to divide the word count by sum of all counts `(prob = count(word) / sum(count of all words in dict)` and write this probability into new file called `x.txt`.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import sys
filename = 'abc.txt'
new_dict ={}
total_count = 0
with open(filename, "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        words = line.split()  

        for word in words:
            word = word.lower()

        if not word in new_dict:
             new_dict[word] = 1
        else:
            new_dict[word] +=1
            total_count +=1
probab = new_dict[word]/ total_count
print(probab)
fp.close()
output_file = 'x.txt'
with open(output_file, "w") as fs:
           fs.write(str(probab))               
fs.close()
```

and my output is 0.0006865437426441742

Comment: `and my input is 0.0006865437426441742` Are you sure this is your input?

Comment: You're only adding one word from each line to the dict. You may want to move the if-else blocks under the for-loop. Please fix issues with your code first.

Comment: Doing just this won't be too effective. As you have mentioned that the file contains sentences so you might miss the same word a '.' or a ',' or other characters. eg.`"i am going"` will give you `['i,','am','going']` and `" i am going."`  will give you `['i', 'am','going.']`.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for updating my answer multiple times. I shouldn't upload my answer when I'm tired.

I'm going to ignore the running time complexity to avoid confusing you.

If you want to know, this will run in *O(n^2) time*. This can be simplified to *O(n log n) time* using a tree, but using and explaining a tree might confuse a beginner.

The simplest way to do and undertand this is as follows:

```py
    # you don't need "import os" in this case.
    new_dict = {}

    # This is to open the file to get the count of all words:
    filename = 'abc.txt'    
    with open(filename, "r") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            # For this to work, make sure the words don't end with any punctuation.
            # If any words end with a punctuation, take a look into re.sub()
            words = line.split()
    
            for word in words:
                word = word.lower()
    
                if word not in new_dict:
                    new_dict[word] = 1
                else:
                    new_dict[word] += 1
    
    # This is to calculate the count of all words:
    total_words = sum(new_dict.values())

    # This is used to get the probability of each word.
    output_file = 'x.txt'
    with open(output_file, "w") as fs:
        # The dictionary is set as: {dictionary_name[key] : value}
        for key, value in sorted(new_dict.items()):
            probability = value / total_words
            fs.write(key + ": " + str(probability) + "\n")
```

---

- #### Using `for x_variable in collection_variable`

When you are using `for x_variable in collection_variable`, you need to make sure any code using the `x_variable` resides inside of the for each loop. In this case, I pushed anything that uses word to make sure the `word` variable is accessible because you are calling it from inside the `for word in words` iterator.

- #### When to call `file.close()`

When opening files with the `with open(...)` function, you don't need to explicitly close it. You can just leave the `with open` code block and the garbage collector will know you are done with that file. However, if you do `open(...)` without the `with` operator, then yeah, you need to call `fs.close()`

- #### How `sorted(variable)` works

With simple data types like **string**, **int**, **float**, **tuple**, **list**, **dictionary**, they already include comparison functions, so you can use `sorted(variable)` to sort them. However, if you have your own data type or object, you need to define the comparison functions for the sorted() to work. Read more about `sorted(variable)` on [Python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The last version what I got was: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0179a6549b87667c3448fa75d12bad1

Comment: @Marishka33, I uploaded [hopefully] my last answer update. I just want to make sure it works for you.